# Keybinding move word in JRuby irb on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, jruby, irb, key-bindings

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81272/mac-os-x-terminal-move-cursor-word-by-word), except in JRuby (it works in MRI Ruby). Alt-left prints a "b" in my console. Very annoying!

To clarify, I've setup my terminal as described in [this article](http://www.mactips.org/archives/2007/12/20/word-movement-in-terminal/), mapping option-left to escape-b.

Answer (score 0):

Move word left is `ctrl-g`, don't know what move word right is though. And I would like to use `alt-left` / `alt-right`.