# Vim in Mac OS X Terminal: Move cursor word by word

Tags: macos, vim

I have followed the guidance in [Is there any way in the OS X Terminal to move the cursor word by word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81272/mac-os-x-terminal-move-cursor-word-by-word) and now in terminal I can move cursor word by word.

However, in Vim, I am only able to move backward word by word.  I cannot move forward word by word, no matter I set \033f to `option+cursor-right` or `shift+cursor-right`.  The only workaround I figured out is to go to normal mode and click `<w>` to move to next word.  Any idea about how to fix that?  Thanks.

Comment: `w` in normal mode is the best way to move word by word.

Comment: You can use ^O in insert mode to run one normal mode command and stay in insert mode, such as ^Ow.

Answer (score 12):

`w` is not a workaround. It's the primary way to move word by word (see also: `W`, `b`, `B`, `e`, `E`). What you want is a workaround that won't help you learn Vim at all.

Answer (score 3):

Some may argue that moving around with [VIM native keyboard shortcuts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_the_right_moves) is not a workaround, but for me it sure is both very inconvenient and very inefficient. Especially the part where you need to switch between `insert` mode and `normal` mode just to move to the next word.

That's why I came up with a solution based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/123937/how-to-jump-to-the-beginning-or-end-of-line-in-vim-os-x) on SuperUser. The idea is to map input provided by the `Terminal.app` directly in VIM. The answer on SU shows what to put into your `vimrc` file for the Home/End keys to work as expected.

My tweaked version below includes the `Option+arrow` (or `Alt+arrow`) navigation on words. I've tried to mimic the behavior of Terminal's moving around as close as I could get. So pressing `Option+Right` (`Alt+Right`) will move the caret to the next character after the word (as opposed to the last character of the word, which is VIMs `w` native bahavior).

```
let tp=$TERM_PROGRAM
if tp == 'Apple_Terminal'
  :" map Mac OS X Terminal.app

  " map Home/End:
  :map <ESC>[H <Home>
  :map <ESC>[F <End>
  " small 'o' letter in <C-o> means no exit from the insert mode
  :imap <ESC>[H <C-o><Home>
  :imap <ESC>[F <C-o><End>
  :cmap <ESC>[H <Home>
  :cmap <ESC>[F <End>

  " map Option+Left/Option+Right:
  " for this to work you must have the bindings in Settings > Keyboard set
  " as follows:
  " 'option cursor left' to '\033b'
  " 'option cursor right' to '\033f'
  :map <ESC>f el
  :imap <ESC>b <C-o>b
  :imap <ESC>f <C-o>el
  :cmap <ESC>f el
endif
```

As a small, but significant bonus you get Home/End navigation without exiting the `insert` mode. Tested on `10.8.5`.

Comment: This is fantastic, but i've noticed in insert mode I'll get an extra "l" appended to the move. Ex if `[x]` cursor.. `[x]foo bar` then ⌥ <Right> --> `fool[x] bar` --> ⌥ <Right> `folo balr[x]`

Comment: ^^ update to the above... just make `:imap <ESC>f <C-o>e`... the `l` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Let me clear a few things up for you. Bash (the shell program running inside the terminal) has the behavior you are used to. (Using Alt+f to move forward by word, and Alt+b to move backward by word.) This was originally done to be like Emacs. You can use the command

```
set -o vi
```

to switch to vim behavior. In this mode, you can use Esc to switch to normal mode, and move around like in vim; then press i to go back to insert mode.

So don't be surprised that Vim isn't trying to act like Emacs. The whole power behind vim lies behind these simple motions.

Comment: `-bash: bindkey: command not found`. I don't think it is a standard command. Besides `Alt+character` is often used for accented characters in regional alphabets.

Comment: My bad. Somehow forgot I was running zsh.

Answer (score 0):

As of Nov'23, these simple shortcuts work for me with vim (insert mode) open in Terminal app. This works OOTB, no editing of rc files etc. is needed.

`Shift+left/right` - move word by word

`Fn+Shift+left/right` - jump to beginning or end of the line

`Fn+Shift+up/down` - page up/page down