# In Terminal.app, option+arrow keys no longer move by word

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Having done a little research on this, I know that option+left arrow and option+right arrow *do not* by default move by word in the OS X Terminal application. But mine did, until about a week ago.

The only thing that's changed is oh-my-zsh updated. I see that it has

```
bindkey "^[[1;5C" forward-word  
bindkey "^[[1;5D" backward-word
```

defined but I don't know what those keys are. GitHub's last recorded change to the file was 24 days go and not related to those keys, so this must predate the latest update.

I have also tried the "Use option as meta key" option under Preferences > Settings > Keyboard. That only results in printing `[D` and `[C` when I hit option+left arrow and option+right arrow.

Comment: Can't replicate. It works as expected for my. Running Mountain Lion (1.8.5).

Comment: In my Terminal.app > Preferences > Keyboard shows `option cursor right` and `left` do those show for you and what values do they have?

Comment: You mean in the Key:Action list? No, I don't have them.

Comment: I do have a Control Cursor Right bound to `\033[5C` and a Control Cursor Left bound to `\033[5D`. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v2h85ju3d2jx5l8/Screenshot%202013-12-27%2010.11.14.png).

Comment: In that list find or add `option cursor right` value `\033f` and `option cursor left` value `\033b`. Quit and restart Terminal.app.

Comment: Yes, after some fiddling I was able to add that myself, using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/81307/1457116) supplemented by [Allan Odegaard's old blog post](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/word-movement-in-terminal/). I didn't need to select "Use option as meta key," nor did I need to restart Terminal. The keystrokes even apply to other Terminal profiles (Basic, Pro, etc).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to fix your issue is to:

- In `Terminal.app > preferences > Settings > Keyboard` there's a Key -> Action list.
- In that list find or add `option cursor left` and `option cursor right` and set their values to `\033b` and `\033f` respectively.
- Quit and restart Terminal.app

Comment: In iTerm2 this also works, but you select `Send Escape Sequence` and `f` and `b` respectively for your current profile (Preferences > Profiles > *Default > Keys > Key Mappings for Ctrl Left/Right arrow)

Comment: Adding a blog link for this setup on iterm2 having explaination
https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda/use-and-to-jump-forwards-backwards-words-in-iterm-2-on-os-x