# OS X Terminal shortcut: Jump to beginning/end of line

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that I can jump to the beginning and end of a line inside the OS X terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. But I'm so used to jumping with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> arrow and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> arrow from my editor, that I would love to use these shortcuts for the terminal too.

I haven't found a solution with Google, so maybe here someone can help.

**Update**

As in the comments, I tried the solution from [How to move the cursor word by word in the OS X Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81272/is-there-any-way-in-the-os-x-terminal-to-move-the-cursor-word-by-word/81299#81299)

Unfortunately, the Terminal settings seems to not include <kbd>Cmd</kbd> as a Modifier Key, as you can see here:

[image: Modifier Keys of Terminal]

Comment: can't you adapt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/81299/2307070) ?

Comment: I've updated my question, see above

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think so. I tried it, it works with `Option + right-arrow`, but not with `Cmd + right-arrow`

Comment: You're right, my fault, I've got hard days on a PC

Comment: More useful shortcuts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542996

Comment: simply `fn + left` or `fn + right`

Answer (score 196):

```
fn + shift + leftArrow = goto beginning of line
fn + shift + rightArrow = goto end of line
```

these work for me

Comment: I didn't need to hold the shift key. `fn + leftArraw` or `fn + rightArrow` worked for me. Maybe it helps!

Comment: @BharatGupta fn+leftArrow works in some terminal applications (e.g. VI), but doesn't work in the terminal command line.

Comment: Using iTerm2, fn+left and fn+right work without shift. With shift, they don't work. ctrl+a and ctrl+e also work.

Comment: I'm a new Mac user and I'm disgusted by how hard everything is in Mac vs Windows!  The hardware is good, but the software is horrible (i.e. not user friendly.)

Comment: If you are new on Mac think simple, coz when you use windows for long term, you are used to always use complicated path... with Mac you have to think very simple...  and most of time you got it. It was like that for me when I switch for PC to Mac

Comment: Nice, only problem on mac usb/bluetooth keyboards is the `fn`key above the arrow keys. For people who play the guitar pressing that 3 buttons might work well :), so the default option `^ + e` might be better.

Comment: It's not simple though. A lot of things are extremely inconsistent and not user friendly. This very question is an example of one. Navigation and text manipulation keyboard shortcuts are completely different between different applications.

Comment: I have a windows keyboard. Throw it away because no answers here work? But the OPs solution with Ctrl+a and Ctrl+e does it.

Comment: @Supernini Windows: press `Home` key which on some laptops will require also pressing the Fn key, but will always be labelled.
Mac: come to StackOverflow to find answer.
To paraphrase the old ads, 'Define Simple'.

Comment: In Monterey 12.6, it doesn't work..

Comment: Simple means "it doesn't exist. Hold down the arrow key until you get there. No extra keys to learn."  See, simple!

Answer (score 86):

**Control + A** for goto the beginning and **Control + E** to goto the end

Comment: Great, that works but how can I change the key mapping?

Answer (score 56):

In the latest Mac OS You can use `shift` + `home` or `shift` + `end`

Comment: how do yo have a HOME / END key. I only have arrows on my keyboard

Comment: I use an external keyboard

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm fn+left=home, fn+right=end, fn+up=pageup, fn+down=pagedown

Answer (score 39):

I use a handy app called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to do this, and many other things.  It's free and open source.

It's a keyboard remapper, with a lot of handy presets for many common remaps that people may want to do.

As you can see from the screenshot, this remap is included as a preset in Karabiner.

[image: Screenshot of Karabiner preferences showing the preset to map cmd+left/right to ctrl+a/e]

Hope this helps.  Happy remapping!

Comment: Now it supports Sierra and even higher. Here's the link to some pre-defined rules from [Karabiner website](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/).

Comment: In @JavaXu's link in the comment directly above me, search for `Navigation in Terminal Apps` to find the rule you need to import.

Comment: @electrovir I can't find that rule in the link. Is it gone now?

Comment: @jaquinodev the `Navigation in Terminal Apps` shortcuts config seems to have been replaced with `Keyboard shortcuts for Terminal apps` which does _not_ have the shortcuts needed for this question. Since I still have the configs laying around [I uploaded it to GitHub (with instructions) here](https://github.com/electrovir/karabiner-elements-terminal-navigation).

Answer (score 29):

As setup in the terminal using `vi`:

The `Home` button on a Macbook Pro keyboard: `Fn + Left Arrow`.

The `End` button on a Macbook Pro keyboard: `Fn + Right Arrow`.

Comment: This question was about the Mac OS terminal, not `vi`. `vi` is an application that can be run inside a terminal.

Answer (score 24):

Here I found a tweak for this, **without any third party tool**. This will make the following shortcut to work:

```
 fn + right: to go to the end of the line.
 fn + left: to go to the beginning of the line.
```

- Open terminal preferences.(`cmd + ,`).
- Go to your selected theme and then to the keyboard tab.

[image]

- And add a new entry as following.
  [image]
  [image]
- That's all. Now close and check.

  Hope it helps.

EDIT: Refer to the comment by @Maurice Gilden below for more insights.

Comment: That will just enter "001" or "005". The backslash is missing and I could not find any way to manually add it. What you can do however is, press Ctrl+A for "\001" and Ctrl+E for "\005" while inside the text box.

Comment: This should be the absolute correct answer. All of the 3rd party apps are either broken or no longer maintained and fn+shift+leftArrow no longer works on Mojave.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. However, I selected "End" rather than "Page Down" for the fn + right arrow mapping.

Comment: Thank you brethren Abhishek, Maurice, Salyangoz and nedblorf, you the best. The only thing which left to figure out for me is to enable this functionality when working from terminal apps like the MidnightCommander (espetially when panels are switched off with the Ctrl+O).

Comment: On my windows keyboard, I now have pos 1 as 'go to begin of line' and end as 'go to end of line' which is what I want. I could enter backslash, but not one backslash but two so I followed Maurice.

Comment: @Maurice Gilden is the answer

Answer (score 18):

For iterm2:

Go to Profiles / Open Profiles / Keys

Set    `Cmd + left_arrow_key` to Send `Hex Code 001`

Set `Cmd + right_arrow_key` to Send `Hex Code 005`

This allows you to use `Cmd + arrow_keys` to move from beginning to end of the line.

Comment: as per @bhekman's comment: "Using iTerm2, fn+left and fn+right work without shift. With shift, they don't work. ctrl+a and ctrl+e also work."

Comment: I don't see `cmd` as a modifier key option, same as in the original question

Comment: @electrovir just hold it down and press the arrow keys

Comment: See "Unfortunately, the Terminal settings seems to not include Cmd as a Modifier Key, as you can see here" in the original question. I have the same problem. My comment was about creating the key setting, not executing it.

Comment: @electrovir it sounds like you are in the wrong place. there is no modifier. 
open iterm. go to preferences. go to profiles. press the "+" button to the left of "Load Preset". There are two fields: "Keyboard Shortcut" and "Action" for keyboard shortcut hold command press the left arrow key. then for action -> "send hex code -> 001 "

Comment: Ah, I skipped over your "For iterm2" qualifier. I just assumed this was for Terminal since that's what the question was for :) Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 15):

As per the official website of Apple

```
control + A - Move to the beginning of the line

control + E - move to the end of the line
```

[terminal shortcuts by Apple's official site](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/terminal/trmlshtcts/mac)

Comment: thank you, i accidentally came across `ctr + A` and I was looking for the opposite :)

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if this will work for you (I still use `OS 10.8`), but these work for my terminal:

```
home = move cursor to the start of the line
shift+end = move cursor to the end of the line

alt+leftArrow = move one "word" to the left
alt+rightArrow = move one "word" to the right
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In 10.12 Sierra, it looks like it's shift + home to go to the beginning. the others listed here work as listed.

Answer (score 8):

For latest mac os, Below shortcuts works for me.

Jump to beginning of the line == **shift + fn + RightArrow**

Jump to ending of the line == **shift + fn + LeftArrow**

Answer (score 7):

You could download **[Better Touch  Tool](https://folivora.ai/).**

It's an app that allows you to make custom key-bindings and shortcuts over your entire system or individual apps.

Using it, you could make a shortcut in the terminal that emulates ctrl-a/ctrl-e whenever you press cmd-left/cmd-right, respectively.

[image]

I definitely recommend it!
I've been using it for years and I have over 50 shortcuts spread across several different apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, your link is broken

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I fixed it.

Comment: Hey @Jacob what would be the 'triggered predefined action' to go beginning or end of the terminal command?

Comment: Oer, you should use the "Trigger Other Keyboard Shortcut" option, and enter Ctrl-A to go to the beginning of the terminal command, and Ctrl-E to go to the end.

Comment: This software seems to be outdated. It is not maintained anymore.

Comment: Nah, the developer just moved to a new website. BetterTouchTools is still actively maintained (and I still use it to this day!)
https://folivora.ai/

Comment: I have updated the link in the answer itself and added a screenshot. This is a great and supereasy method if you already have BetterTouchTool or if you'd like to try it.

Answer (score 7):

`fn + leftArraw or fn + rightArrow` worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

**Text Navigation Shortcuts**

- Jump to beginning of a line – `Command+Left Arrow`
- Jump to end of a line – `Command+Right Arrow`
- Jump to beginning of current word –
  `Option+Left Arrow`
- Jump to end of current word – `Option+Right Arrow`
- Jump to beginning of all text – `Command+Up Arrow`
- Jump to end
  of all text – `Command+Down Arrow`

**Text Selection Shortcuts**

- Select text to beginning of a line – `Shift+Command+Left Arrow`
- Select text to end of a line – `Shift+Command+Right Arrow`
- Select text to beginning of current word – `Shift+Option+Left Arrow`
- Select text to end of current word – `Shift+Option+Right Arrow`
- Select text to beginning of all text – `Shift+Command+Up Arrow`
- Select text to end of all text – `Shift+Command+Down Arrow`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Bloke it not only answer the question but also added other option related to Text navigation and selection

Comment: @AbdurRahman it didn't answer the question because `Command+Arrow` to jump to end/beginning of line didn't work on OP's machine (as imply in the question). The other commands that you listed are not part of the question

Answer (score 2):

in iterm2

> **fn + leftArraw or fn + rightArrow**

this worked for me

Comment: The question was about the Mac OS X terminal

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `Option + left-arrow` or `Option + right-arrow` for moving the cursor to the start or end of the line.

**Mac Os Version**: Catalina

Comment: Worked for me using Mac OS Version: Monterey, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i have the same issue on MacOS 12 (Monterey) - want to go to beginning and end of the line with fn + arrow keys.
When you are trying to write '\' in that text field, it becomes '\\' (with escape).
You need to paste this text (copy from some text editor, o from terminal) \001 (home) and \005 (end) in field.

[image]